# Resolving 'No-Conflict' mode with JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using a JQuery plugin which looks like:

```
    /* Copyright (c) 2006-2007 Mathias Bank (http://www.mathias-bank.de)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) 
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 * 
 * Version 2.1
 * 
 * Thanks to 
 * Hinnerk Ruemenapf - http://hinnerk.ruemenapf.de/ for bug reporting and fixing.
 * Tom Leonard for some improvements
 * 
 */
jQuery.fn.extend({
/**
* Returns get parameters.
*
* If the desired param does not exist, null will be returned
*
* To get the document params:
* @example value = $(document).getUrlParam("paramName");
* 
* To get the params of a html-attribut (uses src attribute)
* @example value = $('#imgLink').getUrlParam("paramName");
*/ 
 getUrlParam: function(strParamName){
      strParamName = escape(unescape(strParamName));

      var returnVal = new Array();
      var qString = null;

      if ($(this).attr("nodeName")=="#document") {
        //document-handler

        if (window.location.search.search(strParamName) > -1 ){

            qString = window.location.search.substr(1,window.location.search.length).split("&");
        }

      } else if ($(this).attr("src")!="undefined") {

        var strHref = $(this).attr("src")
        if ( strHref.indexOf("?") > -1 ){
            var strQueryString = strHref.substr(strHref.indexOf("?")+1);
            qString = strQueryString.split("&");
        }
      } else if ($(this).attr("href")!="undefined") {

        var strHref = $(this).attr("href")
        if ( strHref.indexOf("?") > -1 ){
            var strQueryString = strHref.substr(strHref.indexOf("?")+1);
            qString = strQueryString.split("&");
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }


      if (qString==null) return null;


      for (var i=0;i<qString.length; i++){
            if (escape(unescape(qString[i].split("=")[0])) == strParamName){
                returnVal.push(qString[i].split("=")[1]);
            }

      }


      if (returnVal.length==0) return null;
      else if (returnVal.length==1) return returnVal[0];
      else return returnVal;
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

I know that this is because of the "No-Confict" mode that WordPress has, and I'm wondering how to resolve this? This code is from a plug-in and I can edit it, but I don't want to have to replace every `$` that the plugin has.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: we would need to know more about the plugin. What you have given us so far shows the beginning a correctly written plugin that will work with `jQuery.noConflict`.

Comment: I added the whole plugin

Comment: every occurrence of `$` should be changed to `jQuery`, or you can wrap the entire plugin in an IFFE.

Comment: @KevinB, maybe you didn't read my whole question. I specifically said, "This code is from a plug-in and I can edit it, but I don't want to have to replace every $ that the plugin has."

Comment: And can someone please tell me how this is off-topic? Wtf?

Comment: you don't have a choice. either replace every occurence, or wrap in in an IIFE.

Comment: Is it possible that the plugin is rendering in a block above the no-conflict mode in WP? I've done that before where I rendered it in the head block and it should've been in the foot. Just a thought.

Comment: @Blaine it was marked off topic with this reason: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist "

Comment: Most plugins are wrapped in an IIFE sothat inside the IIFE the plugin author is free to use `$` without worry of conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the plugin in an anonymous function, like this.

```
(function($) {
   //Plugin code here
})(jQuery)
```